# How do I print out a positive or negative decimal number in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to find positive and negative numbers within a string through regular expressions. I've gotten a regex pattern to work, but how do I spit back a negative sign for negative numbers? I know I can have two `if` statements but I was wondering if there was a regex shortcut.

```
my $number = 'I have a number that is a-32.10a';

if($number =~ /[-]?(\d+)(\.?(\d+))/){
    print "Number: $1$2\n";
}else{
    print "No match\n";
}
```

returns only 32.10; I'd like the `-` returned as well.

Conversely, if `$number` is an integer e.g. `= 234`, how can I only print out integers and print `no match` for decimals?

Answer (score 5):

You did not include optional `-` into your capture group.

This code works:

```
my $string = 'I have a number that is a-32.10a';

my ($number) = ($string =~ /(-?\d+\.?\d+)/);

if (defined $number) {
    print "Number: $number\n";
} else {
    print "Not a number!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the `-` why don't you just use `/(-?\d+\.?\d+)/`? And why you print a "Integer" while -32.10 is actually not?

Comment: Sorry, that should've been "number". Thanks for the help